# Get PostgreSQL execution plan with Drill query

Tags: postgresql, postgis, apache-drill

I need to get the execution plan of a query that execute from Apache Drill using the PostgreSQL storage plugin (not the Drill execution plan, but the PostGIS one).

So I enable the explain plan logs with following commands;

```
SET auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0;
SET auto_explain.log_analyze = true;
```

And if I execute a query from pgAdmin, it shows the statement and the plan. But if I execute the same query from Drill, it does not log anything.

Do you know why this happens and how can be solved this situation?

**Note**: I checked the connection and it's ok, they are the same in pgAdmin and Drill, also in Drill I execute queries and I get results, so I assume that there is no connection problems.

Comment: Did you install the [auto_explain extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html)?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are executing the `SET` commands from a postgres command line, so those settings would only apply to Drill's postgres session. In order to apply those settings to Drill's postgres session, try adding those properties to Drill's storage plugin configuration. Here is an example configuration for those properties:

```
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver",
  "url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432;auto_explain.log_min_duration=0;auto_explain.log_analyze=true",
  "username": "postgres",
  "enabled": true
}
```